# Does mono support interacting with ADFS?

Tags: c#, mono, owin, adfs, identityserver3

Wanted to know whether anyone can shed light on interacting with ADFS when working *on mono*. If there's something out there that uses IdentityServer or more generally, OWIN, even better.

Our current basic test shows `Mono.Security` + `System.IdentityModel` don't have enough of an implementation for `Saml2SecurityTokenHandler`, at least we get exceptions left right and center from this class.

Following [this](https://github.com/IdentityModel/Thinktecture.IdentityModel.45/issues/145#issuecomment-139741975) thread, looks like there's at least one SAML project that is open source, perhaps this might be of some use?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Mono is an implementation of the .NET framework.

ADFS requires various Windows server libraries to work.

So I doubt ADFS runs on Mono.

In general, you can federate ADFS with identityserver and ADFS can handle client side applications using OWIN as the wrapper around the actual protocol.

Also be aware that although WIF and OWIN support SAML tokens, there is no official support for the SAML protocol.

Comment: Thanks @nzpcmad. Agree with your first statement; I don't need to provide ADFS, or "run" ADFS on mono. Instead I'd like to be able to interact / integrate with it.

While IdentityServer uses OWIN, it's not really related to the topic, for example if an implementation exists that uses Web API or another web stack it would still be useful; we could consider bridging from one to the other. Or if it's open source follow its approach for our web stack.